# What is the terminology used for non-invasive treatments?

Tags: terminology

When a condition is being treated by non-invasive, non-drug methods, what is that called?

For example, if the patient has elevated blood pressure and the doctor recommends exercising, a low salt diet and a weight loss program only; what is that kind of treatment called?

Answer (score 3):

Non-surgical, non-medical treatments are typically referred to as involving "lifestyle"; lifestyle intervention, lifestyle modification, lifestyle treatment, lifestyle change, etc. "Lifestyle factors" or just simply "lifestyle" is also used to mean behavioral factors that influence health (diet, exercise, smoking/drinking, etc).

https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C50&q=%22lifestyle+modification%22&btnG=
https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C50&q=%22lifestyle+intervention%22&btnG=
https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C50&q=%22lifestyle+change%22&btnG=
https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C50&q=%22lifestyle+treatment%22&btnG=

You may find other terms used, too, like "behavior"; like with most things in language, there's more than one way to say something.